# Question about total variation

Tags: functional-analysis

When I was reading http://mathpost.la.asu.edu/~ylin/YLin_thesis.pdf , I didn't understand the following. Why is TV the sum of "jumps".

It seems to me that (1.24) is a formula of arc length. But why are $x_1, x_2$ and $x_4$ equal?

For example, consider $$x_1(t) = t^2, \quad x_2(t) = t^3$$
Then
$$ TV(x_1) = \int_0^1|2t|dt = 2 $$
$$ TV(x_2) = \int_0^1|3t^2|dt = 3 $$
Where am I wrong?

I am newbie for 'total variation'. So any recommendation for self-study material is also welcome.

---

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, $ x_1, x_2$ and $x_4$ are monotonic and increasing. Another formulation of the Total Varation is:

$TV(x) = \sup_P{ \sum_{i=0}^{n_P-1} \lvert(f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i))\rvert}  $

Where the supremum is taken over all finite partitions of the domain of $f$. This may be a more intuitive definition.

Comment: I know this formula, but I can't understand my original question.

Comment: Essentially, the function is partitioned into intervals over which it is monotonic, and the variation over each of these intervals is added up.

Comment: Is there any relationship between it and arc length formula?

Comment: I have added my question. Could you see it?

Comment: @topy TV is sort of a "purely vertical" arc length. A line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ is shorter than the union of the three line segments going from $(0,0)$ to $(1/2,0)$, then from $(1/2,0)$ to $(1/2,1)$, then from $(1/2,1)$ to $(1,1)$. Yet the two corresponding functions have the same TV. Another illustration is given when you dilate the domain. If $L>1$, $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $g : [0,L] \to \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=g(Lx)$, then $f$ has a shorter arc length than $g$ but they have the same TV.

Comment: Thanks, but how is $\int|\nabla x(t)|dt$ "purely vertical" arc length? It seems usual arc length formula. At this point, I am confused.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the notation, but keep in mind it is not a $\Delta$, but a "Nabla" $\nabla$. Most likely similar to: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BackwardDifference.html

Comment: I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

First, if this was an arc length formula, then the length of $x^n$ on $[0, 1]$ would go to infinity with increasing n, while you want it to approach $2$ (two sides of a unit square). The $|\cdot|$ is actually a metric and your arcs are defined on a plane, i.e. $\mathbf{g}:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \mathbf{g} = (g_1, g_2)$ where $g_1=t$ and $g_2=f(t)$, so the arc length is actually

$$ \int_a^b|\mathbf{g}'(t)| = \int_a^b\sqrt{g'_1(t)^2+g'_2(t)^2} = \int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2} $$

More importantly, the way you compute the integrals is incorrect. The Newton integral is calculated by subtracting *primitive functions* at the boundary values, not the integrand directly.

The primitive function for $2t$ is $F(t)=t^2+C$ again, so

$$ \int_0^1|2t|dt = F(1) - F(0) = (1)^2 - (0)^2 = 1 $$

and similar for $3t^2$ it's $F(t)=t^3+C$:

$$ \int_0^1|3t^2|dt = F(1) - F(0) = (1)^3 - (0)^3 = 1 $$